# Can't lauch spyder on new envs

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder, prompt

When i lauch spyder on another env than "base" i get this error :

```
fromIccProfile: failed minimal tag size sanity
C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 252, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1822, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\utils.py", line 289, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 773, in setup
    PLUGIN_REGISTRY.register_plugin(self, PluginClass,
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugin_registration\registry.py", line 342, in register_plugin
    instance = self._instantiate_spyder5_plugin(
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugin_registration\registry.py", line 184, in _instantiate_spyder5_plugin
    plugin_instance = PluginClass(main_window, configuration=CONF)
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\api\plugins\new_api.py", line 331, in __init__
    container.setup()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pythonpath\container.py", line 55, in setup
    self._load_pythonpath()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pythonpath\container.py", line 136, in _load_pythonpath
    system_path = get_system_pythonpath()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\pythonpath\utils.py", line 31, in get_system_pythonpath
    env = get_user_env()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 71, in get_user_env
    env_dict = get_user_environment_variables()
  File "C:\Users\esto5\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py", line 60, in get_user_environment_variables
    res = stdout.decode().strip().split(os.linesep)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 247: invalid start byte
```

I find nothing on internet about this specific problem. I tried too much
update remove install

installation with conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder lauch it but don't work more

Comment: Weird problem but I think your env name has to be the problem here. What is it called?

Comment: i tried PIP, PIPS, ALL. Same problems with all of them

Comment: Not the question I asked. It seems spyder has a problem understanding your env name . 
res = stdout.decode().strip().split(os.linesep) From this line you can see it's trying to split something , probably your environment name not entirely sure about it. But I think it has to do with your env name having some weird character inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone get this problem, in the file :

```
C:\Users\User_name\anaconda3\envs\PIP\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\environ.py
```

I replaced the line :

```
res = stdout.decode().strip().split(os.linesep)
```

By :

```
res =str(stdout).strip().split(os.linesep)
```